# Rails Date Format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date

I am developing a rails 3.2 app.
I have the following configuration in initializers/time_format.rb file.

```
Date::DATE_FORMATS.merge!(default: "%m/%d/%Y")
Date::DATE_FORMATS.merge!(db: "%m/%d/%Y")
Time::DATE_FORMATS.merge!(default: "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
Time::DATE_FORMATS.merge!(db: "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

I want all date format %m/%d/%Y.
It works fine except that input element shows "yyyy-mm-dd" format?
What am I missing?

Thanks.

Sam

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about the date_select form helper?

Maybe try modifying your form like this?

```
date_select("article", "written_on", :order => [:month, :day, :year])
```

Check the [API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-date_select) for more details.